# How to filter a specific entry from "--help" option?

Tags: bash, unix

many tools in unix offer the parameter "--help" for showing possible parameters. In case this is standardized - is there any easy way to show the help entry for a specific parameter?

E.g. something like `wget --no-glob --help` which should show information about the parameter `--no-glob`

I know that one can filter something like this out with grep or similar tools. I'm asking specifically for built-in support for this scenario.

Best regards

Comment: Sadly, no, the formatting for a program's `--help` output isn't standard enough to guarantee that you can parse it programmatically for any given program. As [shtuff.it says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23375210/418413) you can try to use `grep`, but it may capture too little. If you use GNU grep's `-C`, `-B` or `-A` flags, it might help, or it could capture too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--help` is a common *convention*, not a standard. *Some* people program extra helpful `--help` options like you've described, but those are pretty rare.

In *most* cases you can jump directly to the relevant entry with something like:

```
wget --help | less -p '--no-glob'
```

From `less`'s `man` page:

```
   -ppattern or --pattern=pattern
          The  -p  option  on  the  command line is equivalent to specifying +/pattern; that is, it
          tells less to start at the first occurrence of pattern in the file.
```

Answer (score 1):

Grepping a man page is the closest I can think of:

```
man wget | grep 'glob'
```

works with --help too:

```
wget --help | grep glob
```

Use -A[num] and -B[num] to get lines after and before:

```
> wget --help | grep convert-links
    -k,  --convert-links      make links in downloaded HTML or CSS point to
> wget --help | grep convert-links -A1
    -k,  --convert-links      make links in downloaded HTML or CSS point to
                              local files.
```